# Нижний Toolbar перекрывает остальной контент

Tags: android

Есть Toolbar, который закреплен в нижней части активити и есть TabHost с двумя вкладками. При скроллинге любой из вкладок до низа, Toolbar как бы прикрывает все то, что находится внизу. Пришлось прийти к такому решению:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/order_from"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp">

                    <!-- Контент первой вкладки -->
                </ScrollView>

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/order_to"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp">

                    <!-- Контент второй вкладки --> 
                </ScrollView>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/order_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Как видно из XML, я задал `android:paddingBottom="100dp"` для каждой вкладки. Но мне кажется, это нарушает правила адаптивности. Как можно решить эту проблему иным путем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте в коде `Toolbar` перед `Tabhost` и в `Tabhost` добавьте строчку `android:layout_above="@id/order_buttons"`, либо используйте `LinearLayout` вместо `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Если использовать `LinearLayout`, то как поместить Toolbar в нижнюю часть?

Comment: просто написать его вторым элементом, `Tabhost` `height` укажите = 0dp и `weight="1"`

Comment: Гениально. Спасибо!