# Android верстка, BottomNavigation поверх окна

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Имеется **activity_main.xml** на котором находятся 3 элемента : 
1. Картинка 
2. Recyclerview 
3. BottomNavigation ,
проблема в том что BottomNavigation находится поверх последнего Recyclerview - элемента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorRootLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/android_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroidExample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="48dp">

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/start_Title"
        android:src="@drawable/bich"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryWhite"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main">
        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: а хотите то чего?

Comment: @Javis_J На скрине видно, что он лежит поверх заслоняя последний элемент Recyclerview , необходимо сделать так чтобы он был под ним, а не заслонял его

Comment: У меня картинки не отображаются. Посмотрите, на что-то подобное отвечал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805447/Нижний-toolbar-перекрывает-остальной-контент/805452#805452

Comment: я бы вам посоветовал перенести bottombar and RecyclerView into the ContraintLayout, and then it push into NestedScrollView. I think, it is solve your problem

Comment: у вас ресайклер match_parent по высоте, т.е. он не учитывает боттом бар. выберите леайут который позволит вам учитываться боттом бар при разметке ресайклера. как уже выше сказали Contraint - отличный вариант

Comment: Спасибо всем за советы! Но видимо я что то делаю не так, как бы я не пытался у меня все равно не выходит это сделать :(